# Where can be assembly-csharp.dll decrypted?

Tags: dll

So I have an android game. Its `Assembly-CSharp.dll` causes `.NET Reflector` to show

> File is not a portable executable. DOS header does not contain 'MZ'
>   signature

It's encrypted. The app seems to decrypt that assembly at app launch time.

So I used `UltraCompare` to point out what is changed from previous version(It wasn't encrypted).

`classes.dex` was identical, so no java code was changed.
`libmain.so` and `libunity.so` was identical, but `libmono.so` had a big change.

There was some new added symbols which seem to be related with encryption such as `TEAEncrypt`, `TEADecrypt`, `TEAEncryptString`, `TEADecryptString`, and some
mono library's C# internal call routine like `ves_icall_System_Security_SecureString_EncryptInternal`.

If it's the means of the encryption, I wander where are those functions called.

There was some changes to `Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll`, `Assembly-UnityScript.dll`, `Assembly-UnityStript-firstpass.dll` with **a same change pattern**. I can't figure out what does this means.

So where can be the **Assembly-CSharp.dll** decrypted at runtime?
Or is there another way without decrypting that at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono is, basically, open source. So anyone can create a Mono implementation that, whenever it reads a chunk of a CIL DLL file, applies encryption to it. Maybe Unity delivers a libmono.so that does encryption with its newest version; maybe the vendor of the game implemented something themselves. You could start checking patch notes of Unity to learn if this is an official new feature; if not, it's likely that the game vendor created their own encrypting libmono.so.

Your TEA functions are, most likely, called within the libmono.so itself. If i had to implement something like that, i'd write wrapper functions `TEAopen`, `TEAread`, `TEAclose` for `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` that decrypt on reading the file, then replace the `f-*` functions in the mono-code that reads a DLL with the `TEA-*` functions.

TEA encryption works with 8-byte chunks, which may be one of the reasons it was used here; if you want to read just a part of the file, you don't need to read everything before your part, except a few bytes to fill the 8-byte-block. But this also means the same 8 input bytes will always result in the same 8 output bytes, if your original DLL has areas with a lot of '\0' bytes, they will result in the same 8 bytes repeated over and over in the encrypted DLL.

While [TEA has a weakness that turns a 128 bit key into 126 effective bits, there seems to be no known plaintext attack on it](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.40.4708&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This means, your observed same change pattern won't help you. So you need to extract the key from the mono implementation yourself. Disassemble that file, especially the `TEAEncrypt` and `TEADecrypt` functions. They should look somewhat like the code from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm). Their second parameter is the key; either try to find out where that key is stored/generated, or do some dynamic analysis, put a breakpoint on those functions, and check what the parameter they get actually is. Also, check if it's really a standard TEA implementation, or maybe XTEA or a different key schedule constant or something. Once you have the key, find a program that takes a file and a TEA key and decrypts it, or roll your own; this shouldn't be too difficult as there are lots of open source TEA implementations in any language of your choice.

Comment: So that same change pattern is not related to encryption. Only Assembly-CSharp.dll was encrypted. Anyway, those functions seems to be almost same with the wikipedia source. I have another question here, what routine is managing the assembly loading?

Comment: What routine is managing the assembly loading? Best check the mono source code (https://github.com/mono). Comparing that source with your libmono.so is probably the fastest way to find out what's different/where the encryption happens.

Comment: yep, I found it.
I used IDA Proximity Browser. I didn't know the purpose of that browser and I finally got it. I searched TEADecryptString's function calls and found the key.